# Bukkit Join Event

Tags: events, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to do some stuff onPlayerJoin but nothing is working. I think it is the bukkit problem. How should I do it? My code:

```
    @EventHandler
private void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    // Join MSGs
    e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Hrac " + ChatColor.RED + e.getPlayer().getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + " se pripojil.");
    e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Hrac " + ChatColor.RED + e.getPlayer().getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + " se odpojil.");
    BukkitScheduler scheduler = getServer().getScheduler();
    scheduler.scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Teleport every join
            Location spawn = (Location) getConfig().get("Spawn");
                e.getPlayer().teleport(spawn);
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage("teleported to spawn");

            // Setting ops
            if(getConfig().get("ops") != null ) {
                ops = (ArrayList<String>) getConfig().getStringList("ops");
            }

            for (String o : ops) {
                if(e.getPlayer().getName() == o) {
                    e.getPlayer().setOp(true);
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage("op");
                }
            }
        }
    }, 20L);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple issues with your code:

You are using the BukkitScheduler.scheduleSyncDelayedTask method instead of the runTaskLater so your task is executed every second instead of one second after the player joined

```
getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable(){}, 20L);
```

You are checking if the player is an op by comparing his name with ==, Strings should be compared with the equals method so do this instead

```
for(String o : ops)
{
    if(e.getPlayer().getName().equals(o))
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

You can't set the join message twice, if you want a multiline join message, send it yourself to all players of the server.

```
getServer().broadcastMessage("hello");
```

Hope this helps, good luck with your plugin development

Comment: new code: still not working, doesn't broadcast http://pastebin.com/EmDnmsfJ

Comment: @xtrontross Try this http://pastebin.com/Q5t0nK6q

Comment: still not working :( no errors in console

Comment: @xtrontross Can you describe more ? Is is compiling ? Is the command working ? What part of the event if ignored, all of it ? Only the runnable part ? (Is the join message changed to yours ?) Are you sure you have a valid plugin.yml and your config has a string list ops ? Do not skip any of these questions please.

Comment: The join msg didn't change. The command and writing to config is working fine. The whole onEnable method is not working.

Comment: Your enable was not declared correctly (OnEnable instead of onEnable) : http://pastebin.com/a1XUfx0T

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with what xtrontros said above, you can still use the bukkit scheduler and it seems you have used it well, a delayed task will not repeat.

However when creating locations from config try parsing it instead of casting it. For example:

```
String[] data = config.getString("spawn").split(",");
Location spawn = new Location(Double.parseDouble(data[0]), Double.parseDouble(data[1]), Double.parseDouble(data[2]), Float.parseFloat(data[3]), Float.parseFloat(data[4]));
```

Then teleport your players there.

You should also make sure you've registered events in that class, in your onEnable() in your Main class add this

```
getServer.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyClassConstructor(), this)
```

Or if the event is in your Main class, use this method instead

```
getServer.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Added @Override upto onEnable() method and working now